# Installed ReText without menu bar!

Tags: menu-bar

I just install ReText using `sudo apt-get install retext`on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It doesn't have a menu bar. And i didn't find configuration file either.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It seems that there's a bug in the appmenu implementation. [Bug #1307619 “All Qt5 applications' menu bar is missing at non-U...” : Bugs : appmenu-qt5 package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appmenu-qt5/+bug/1307619)

Comment: ReText is showing menu bar properly in Xubuntu 14.04. This may be affecting Unity environment only. Or rather, the menu bar in Unity is actually "hidden" in top panel by default. This could be the reason why this was downvoted earlier or last year.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following command in a Terminal to get the name of your icon theme -

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme
```

and take note of it.

Now, edit the *ReText.conf* file -

```
nano ~/.config/ReText\ project/ReText.conf
```

Add the following line to the file -

```
> [General] > iconTheme=<input your Icon Theme name here>
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save.

Close and reopen ReText. The toolbar should now be visible.

[reference](http://www.svenbit.com/2012/05/fix-missing-toolbar-icon-in-retext/)

Comment: sorry if i didn't described it clear. Actually my problem is the menu bar, i.e. `File` `Edit` `Help`，is missing. Also, using `locate ReText.conf` didn't find the configuration file.